# string IndexOf and Replace

Tags: c#, .net, replace

I have just faced this problem today and wonder if someone has any idea about why does this test may fail (depending on culture). The aim is to check if the test text contain two spaces next to each other, which does according to `string.IndexOf` (even if i tell the string to replace all occurrences of two spaces next to each other). After some testing it seems `\xAD` is somehow causing this issue.

```
public class ReplaceIndexOfSymmetryTest
{
    [Test]
    public void IndexOfShouldNotFindReplacedString()
    {
        string testText = "\x61\x20\xAD\x20\x62";
        const string TWO_SPACES = "  ";
        const string ONE_SPACE = " ";
        string result = testText.Replace(TWO_SPACES, ONE_SPACE);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.IndexOf(TWO_SPACES) < 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is going to be your issue, but if you have 3 spaces next to each other in this test then you will end up with 2 next to each other at the end of it.

Comment: The test succeeds for me. Are you sure the code you posted is the same as the code you were testing?

Comment: The problem is `IndexOf` uses culture-specific search while `Replace` uses an ordinal search.
@Chris: the point is that it should fail.

Comment: @Jaroslav: I think you mean 'it may fail' - depends on the current culture?

Comment: @Chris: more like 'he expects it to fail'. Kind of pointless discussion anyway - I've already specified it is culture-specific.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the culture, i fix question, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I've come across the same thing before (although with different characters). Basically `IndexOf` will take various aspects of "special" Unicode characters into account when finding matches, whereas `Replace` just treats the strings as a sequence of code points.

From the [`IndexOf` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx):

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture. The search begins at the first character position of this instance and continues until the last character position.

... and from [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue.

You could use the overload of `IndexOf` which takes a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx), and force it to perform an ordinal comparison though.

Comment: After checking in reflector i found it does use StringComparison.CurrentCulture by default. I should have already learned to avoid defaults in parameters. Thanks Jon.

Comment: [The documentation for String.IndexOf in the .Net Micro Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh400536.aspx) also states that the search is "both case-sensitive and culture-sensitive". But sadly there is no `System.StringComparison` in netmf, nor String.IndexOf that could accept them.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jon said, use [`StringComparison.Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) to get it right.

```
Assert.IsTrue(result.IndexOf(TWO_SPACES, StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0);
```