# Using StringComparer with StringBuilder to search for a string

Tags: c#, string, search, stringbuilder, culture

I need to use globalization rules to search for all occurrences of a string within a document. The pseudocode is:

```
var searchText = "Hello, World";
var compareInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US").CompareInfo;

DocumentIterator start = null; // the start position if a match occurs
var sb = new StringBuilder();

// the document is not a string, but exposes an iterator to its content
for (var iter = doc.Start(); iter.IsValid(); ++iter)
{
    start = start ?? iter; // the start of the potential match

    var ch = iter.GetChar(); 
    sb.Append(ch);

    if (compareInfo.Compare(searchText, sb.ToString()) == 0) // exact match
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"match at {start}-{iter}");
        // not shown: continue to search for more occurrences.
    }
    else if (!compareInfo.IsPrefix(criteria.Text, sb.ToString()))
    {
        // restart the search from the character immediately following start
        sb.Clear();
        iter = start; // this gets incremented immediately
        start = null;
    }
}
```

This delegates to CompareInfo the difficult job of culture-sensitive string matching.

However, the stream-like process implemented by the code has performance issues because it calls StringBuilder.ToString() in every iteration, thus defeating the performance benefit of StringBuilder.

Question: How can I do this search efficiently?

Comment: Why you can't use compareInfo.IndexOf(searchText, sb) where sb - full document?

Comment: @Oleg, I've edited the code to more clearly indicate that the document is not a string, but exposes an iterator to its character content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why not copy the whole document to a stringbuilder first, the use 1 ToString(). Then just use a similar scheme to iterate over all the possible values. Use compareInfo.Compare(criteria.Text, 0, criteria.Text.Length, docString, startIndex, checkLength)

Comment: Ok so I read the comment about the data being too large to copy into a string all at once, so just ignore that. I think you will need to do some chunking as suggested below. Just select some arbitrary size to dump to a string, then call a search function, once you found a match you can clear the sb and re-start from the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use String IndexOf which is culture sensitive and then iterate through your document using indexOf to start the next searc until nothing is found See the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923187/string-indexof-and-replace).

All you need to do to start it off is set the current culture. I'm assuming the `do` loop is then obvious.

Comment: The document is not a string -that's why I've used doc[i] in the pseudocode. I can read it into a single large StringBuilder, but that is problematic in many ways - a) the memory cost, b) the iterator is actually not a simple integer as I've shown - so I'd have to cache those as well.

Comment: Could you not read enough into the string builder to make the size useable and then make the tail of any previous search the start of the new string builder. That way you do not need to iterate on a character by character basis but only on locations of the search text

Comment: How does that avoid calling StringBuilder.ToString() in the loop? Other problems come to mind as well. Could you post a version of code you think will work? Cheers